# Combining subqueries in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries in Access 2007 which together provide the number of children over five in a set. I would like to combine these in SQL to make one query. Would somebody demonstrate the syntax on this example? Or is there a simpler way of getting to the same result?

The first query, called qryChildrenOverFive, is

```
SELECT 
 tblEventParticipants.EventParticipantsID, 
 DateDiff("yyyy", [tblChild.DoB],Date()) AS Age, 
 tblChild.DoB
FROM 
  tblEventParticipants 
  INNER JOIN (tblChild INNER JOIN tblChildParticipant 
  ON tblChild.ChildID = tblChildParticipant.ChildFK) 
  ON tblEventParticipants.EventParticipantsID = 
    tblChildParticipant.EventParticipantFK
WHERE (((tblEventParticipants.EventParticipantsID)=[CurrentID]) 
  AND ((DateDiff("yyyy",[tblChild.DOB],Date()))>5));
```

The other, which uses the above as a subquery, is

```
SELECT qryChildrenOverFive.EventParticipantsID, 
  Count(qryChildrenOverFive.Age) AS NumOverFives
FROM qryChildrenOverFive
GROUP BY qryChildrenOverFive.EventParticipantsID;
```

As a sub-question, why won't Access SQL use the alias 'Age' in the first query in its WHERE clause?

Comment: The alias 'Age' isn't used because there is a logical execution order for a query. For every query, SQL, first analyses the FROM, WHERE and only then the SELECT section, more info here: [link]http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/[/link]

Comment: Useful to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateDiff("yyyy", [tblChild.DoB],Date()) AS Age
```

will only return the difference in calendar years. To calculate the *age*, you need a function like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

and then:

```
AgeSimple([tblChild.DoB]) AS Age
```